# NestJS createParamDecorator return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm using Nest version ^6.7.2

I'm trying to create a createParamDecorator that gets the req.user value from a request.

Inside the createParamDecorator, the req.user has a value, however when I try to get the value in a controller by using the decorator the value is undefined.

```js
const AuthSession = createParamDecorator((data, req) => {
  console.log(req.user); // session data
  return req.user;
});
```

```js
Controller()
export default class AuthController {
  @Get("/token/ping")
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard("jwt"))
  tokenPing(@AuthSession() session: Session) {
    console.log(session); // undefined
    return session;
  }
}
```

Edit: I just tried updating to nestjs v7 and I'm having the same issue

```js
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from "@nestjs/common";

const AuthSession = createParamDecorator((data: any, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
  return { message: "asdf" };
});

export default AuthSession;
```

```js
@Controller()
export default class AuthController {
  @Get("/token/ping")
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard("jwt"))
  tokenPing(@AuthSession() session: Session) {
    console.log(session); // undefined
    return session;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you can get the information firs from ExecutionContext:

```
    import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user;
  },
);
```

check the example in the doc : [Custom decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#param-decorators)

Comment: that's for v7+. I tried updating to v7 and I'm still getting undefined. I updated the original post

Comment: Why you're using Session?

Comment: try without Session

Comment: If I change the type or the name it has no effect

Comment: the console.log in the decorator show the result correctly?

Comment: Yeah, I'm saying if I remove "Session" or rename "session", it has no effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225177/discussion-between-youba-and-user1991252).

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what the issue was. I had a custom validation PipeTransform that returned undefined if the ArgumentMetadata.type was neither "body" nor "param". So now I just return the first argument of the validator's transform method (the input) if the ArgumentMetadata.type is neither "body" nor "param" and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note, to those facing similar issues, I missed out the first data argument which was throwing me an error.

`createParamDecorator((ctx: ExecutionContext)` would result in an undefined context, whereas `createParamDecorator((data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext)` works.